# How to block certain folders in local web server excluding the root folder

Tags: 14.04, apache2, hosts

I am already using the hosts file to block unwanted websites like `127.0.0.1  google.com` . How can I block local users to access `http://mylocal.loc/private` but still want to access other folders like `http://mylocal.loc/wordpress`.
If I do `127.0.0.1 mylocal.loc/private` it is not working.